# xmllist copy assignment or reference assignment?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an `XMLList` in actionscript

```
var xmlList:XMLList = new XMLList();
var xmlList2:XMLList = new XMLList();
xmlList = xmlList2;
```

If I make operations on xmlList2, is xmlList affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's reference, so yes operations on xmlList2 would affect xmlList1. If you want it to not be affected, then instead of xmlList = xmlList2, use xmlList = xmlList2.copy().